# Application.OnTime procedure is running after UserForm click updates are done

Tags: excel, vba, userform

One of the UserForms is taking too much time to update Excel after submit is pressed. If it's taking more than 5 secs, show "Please Wait..." message to the user and close it once the updates are done. Let's say the userform name is "USERFORM_A". I've used a button with caption "Please Wait..." and I'm switching on/off the visibility. In the submit button click event of "USERFORM_A" I'm using the below code:

```
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=fireTime, Procedure:="'PleaseWaitShow ""USERFORM_A""'"
```

And the procedure is as follows

```
Sub PleaseWaitShow(usrFrm As String)
    Dim frm As UserForm
    For Each frm In VBA.UserForms
        If StrComp(TypeName(frm), usrFrm, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            With frm
                .Controls("UserWaitPrompt").Visible = True
                .Controls("UserWaitPrompt").Top = ((.InsideHeight - .Controls("UserWaitPrompt").Height) / 2) + .ScrollTop
                .Controls("UserWaitPrompt").ZOrder
                .Repaint
            End With
            Exit For
        End If
    Next frm
End Sub
```

Checked using debug.print and came to know it's not running the procedure. Changed button click event of "USERFORM_A" as below

```
    t = Timer
    Debug.Print "Before OnTime: " & Now
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Now, Procedure:="Test_TT"
    Debug.Print "After OnTime: " & CDbl(Timer - t)
'Several lines of code
'Wrote below code before the completion message of submit button
    Debug.Print "Before closure: " & CDbl(Timer - t)
```

and before the completion of button click updates and the oputput in the immediate window is as below

```
Before OnTime: 1/22/2020 8:43:58 PM
After OnTime: 0
Before closure: 13.078125
Inside Test_TT: 1/22/2020 8:44:11 PM
```

So it's pretty clear that Application.OnTime is running only after the click event completes or before the busy userform becomes free again.

Kindly let me know what has gone wrong, how to overcome the issue or any other possible workaround please. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: So your issue is that you want to display **"Please Wait..."** after 5 seconds if the form is still executing? If so, you might struggle with that. Excel is a single thread application: which means it has to finish one task at a time and in sequence. Whats wrong with updating the form to say: **"Please Wait..."** and then start your activity?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply @Zac. From the end user perspective showing "Please Wait..." will be frustrating even when the activity is taking not much time say less than 2 sec. If there is no way around I'll go ahead with showing it at the start of the activity.

Comment: Without knowing what the `several lines of code` are doing, it's hard to suggest something. Bottom line, like i said excel is a single thread app so you will have to come up with a clever way to do it within your lines of code

Comment: "Several lines of code" won't make any difference except for the time delay. Are you suggesting to identify the place in the middle of "Several lines of code" reaching which takes approx 5 secs from the start of the activity and call PleaseWaitShow? That could be done for one of the UserForms but there are many other UserForms and there are different scenarios. If that is not what you you are suggesting can you kindly throw some light on how it can be done please.

Comment: Timers have the lowest priority. Any other message in the application's queue will jump it. Timers fire when the program has nothing else to do. Also messages/events only run when you are not in a code block.

Comment: Thanks Zac and Mark for your inputs. As there seems no possible workaround I'll go ahead with displaying "Please wait..." at the start of the activity.